# Re-ordering df.columns alpha numerically

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a df as follows:

```
        Store   Spend_1 Spend_2 Spend_3 Spend_4 Variance_1  Variance_2  Variance_3  Variance_4
0   1   200 230 189 200 -14 16  -6  18
1   2   224 104 240 203 -17 -11 17  -18
2   3   220 168 131 210 10  -9  12  19
3   4   143 187 139 188 -1  -17 -20 -9
4   5   179 121 162 131 6   -25 5   20
5   6   208 158 140 191 16  -14 -22 -6
```

I'm attempting to apply a custom sort on the column names to order it as so :

```
    Store   Spend_1 Variance_1  Spend_2 Variance_2  Spend_3 Variance_3  Spend_4 Variance_4
0   1   200 -14 230 16  189 -6  200 18
1   2   224 -17 104 -11 240 17  203 -18
2   3   220 10  168 -9  131 12  210 19
3   4   143 -1  187 -17 139 -20 188 -9
4   5   179 6   121 -25 162 5   131 20
5   6   208 16  158 -14 140 -22 191 -6
```

I've tried the simple `sorted` but obviously this applies alphabetically, ignoring the integer at the end.

I've toyed around with `enumerating` as `number`, `cols` the `df.columns` changing the strings to ints, applying a sort then using the numbers in the `iloc` but I'm not sure how apply a custom sort that way.

is anyone able to help?

Comment: pass a `key` to sorted? Maybe something like `lambda col: col[-1] + col[:-1]`

Comment: @Dan gets me very very close, how would I apply that ordering to my columns without losing my original column names I guess I can deal with the Store column going else where in another line of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is use `key` parameetr by 2 values - values after `_` converted to `inetegr`s with first values before `_`, but solution is apply for all columns without first with `df.columns[1:]`, so last is added first column by `df.columns[:1].tolist()`:

```
cols = df.columns[:1].tolist() +sorted(df.columns[1:], 
                                       key=lambda x: (int(x.split('_')[1]), x.split('_')[0]))

df = df[cols]
print (df)
   Store  Spend_1  Variance_1  Spend_2  Variance_2  Spend_3  Variance_3  \
0      1      200         -14      230          16      189          -6   
1      2      224         -17      104         -11      240          17   
2      3      220          10      168          -9      131          12   
3      4      143          -1      187         -17      139         -20   
4      5      179           6      121         -25      162           5   
5      6      208          16      158         -14      140         -22   

   Spend_4  Variance_4  
0      200          18  
1      203         -18  
2      210          19  
3      188          -9  
4      131          20  
5      191          -6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `key`t to `sorted` to do your own custom sorting:

```
sorted_columns = sorted(df.columns, key = lambda col: col[-1] + col[:-1])
df[sorted_columns]
```

The ideas is to put the final integer first. This will breakdown if you can go into double digits.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I like your solution as it's a little more readable then the below but it places Store in the final column! Thanks for teaching me something new tho, seriously appreciate it!

Comment: The `split` idea is more generalizable as it will handle double digits. Deal with `'store'` separately imo.

Comment: The problem I see here is that it would fail in the case columns end with digits > 9, otherwise its a nice approach!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach splitting the columns on `_`, reversing the resulting lists so that further sorting prioritises the trailing digits and using [`pandas.Index.argsort`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.argsort.html):

```
df.iloc[:,[0]+[*df.columns.str.split('_').str[::-1].argsort()[:-1]]]

     Store  Spend_1  Variance_1  Spend_2  Variance_2  Spend_3  Variance_3  \
0      1      200         -14      230          16      189          -6   
1      2      224         -17      104         -11      240          17   
2      3      220          10      168          -9      131          12   
3      4      143          -1      187         -17      139         -20   
4      5      179           6      121         -25      162           5   
5      6      208          16      158         -14      140         -22   

     Spend_4  Variance_4  
0      200          18  
1      203         -18  
2      210          19  
3      188          -9  
4      131          20  
5      191          -6
```

Answer (score 1):

simplest way i can think of is defining your own key to the sort

```
df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns, key=lambda x: int(x.split("_")[1]) if "_" in x else 0), axis=1)
```